# Does order of basis vectors changes Matrix of linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $T$ is a operator on V defined as $T(z,w)=(w,0)$ and $M(T)$ be matrix of $T$.

If we choose our basis as $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ then we will be write $$M(T)=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$$. On the other hand if we interchange the vectors in basis, M(T) becomes \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}.

One more problem which I face is when calculating eigenvalues $0$ is the only solution. But using the theorem *"Suppose $T$ has an upper-triangular matrix with respect to some basis of $V$. Then the eigenvalues of $T$ are precisely the entries on the diagonal of that upper-triangular matrix."*
the 2nd matrix tells us $1$ should be an eigenvalue?

Can someone please clarify if I am missing something?

Comment: You have made a mistake. If you interchange the vectors, then you should find that the new matrix of the transformation is
$$
M(T) = \pmatrix{0&0\\1&0}.
$$

Comment: Understood, thanks for pointing that out.